# Get the background color when clicked in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am just newbie to jQuery. I have one div. Under that I have some list of colors. I want that when I will click on those colors then the background color of the div will be change to the clicked color.
My markup for the code is like this

```
<h2>jQuery Bg</h2>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="red" href="">Red</a></li>
    <li><a id="green" href="">Green</a></li>
    <li><a id="blue" href="">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a id="black" href="">Black</a></li>
  </ul>
```

css is like this

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #box {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
  </style>
```

and the jQuery what I have trid so far is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        //alert(event.target.id);
        var bgcolor = event.target.id ;
      jQuery('div#box').css('background','bgcolor');
    });
});
</script>
```

So can someonme kindly tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `css()` value as the variable itself, not a string. Try this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var bgcolor = this.id;
    jQuery('#box').css('background-color', bgcolor);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/gAUf9/)

Some notes; firstly id attributes are unique, so you only need `#box`, not `div#box`. Also, you only want to set the `background-color`. Setting `background` with the colour only will reset all other properties (such as `background-repeat`, `background-image` etc) which may lead to issues later. Finally, you can use the shorted `this.id` to get the id of the clicked element. Finally, you need to use `preventDefault()` to stop the default behaviour of the link navigating away from the page.

Answer (score 2):

**Change**

```
var bgcolor = event.target.id ;
jQuery('div#box').css('background','bgcolor');
```

**To**

```
var bgcolor = $(this).attr('id');
$('div#box').css('background-color',bgcolor);
```

You need to use **background-color**

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#box a").click(function(event) {
              $('div#box').css('background-color', $(this).attr('id') );
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `bgcolor` is a variable not a string literal

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("a").click(function (event) {
        var bgcolor = this.id;
        $('div#box').css('background', bgcolor);
        event.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UP9Ym/)

Comment: but the background color for the div is not activating. It is showing when clicked for a second.I want that it will stay till another color has been clicked. Can you make a fiddle for this?

Comment: @RakeshMishra you are already passing `event` now put `event.preventDefault();` inside code and try

Comment: @RakeshMishra it is because the default action of `a` element was not cancelled

Comment: @ArunPJohny then how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as per below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function(event) {
            var bgcolor = $(this).attr('id');
            jQuery('div#box').css({background:bgcolor});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your html by removing the href from anchor to avoid postback

```
 <h2>jQuery Bg</h2>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="red" >Red</a></li>
    <li><a id="green" >Green</a></li>
    <li><a id="blue" >Blue</a></li>
    <li><a id="black">Black</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And modify one line in your jquery, change

```
jQuery('div#box').css('background','bgcolor');
```

to

```
jQuery('div#box').css('background',bgcolor);
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LTZXk/)

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly modified solution: http://jsfiddle.net/VrGP7/. Click the colored squares to see the larger one change its color to the color of the clicked box.

```
$(".smallBox").click(function(event) {
   var bgcolor = $(this).css('background-color');
   jQuery('div#box').css('background',bgcolor);
});
```